# MySQL leading whitespace with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, whitespace

When I update a field in my MySQL database, it always adds a whitespace to the value.
I tried to remove the whitespace with the trim-command and the replace-command. Neither of them worked. So I expect that it isn't a whitespace but some vague ASCII character. These are the commands I used:

```
this.foo = result.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
this.bar = result.GetValue(0).ToString().Replace(" ","");
```

The field it updates is a VARCHAR(xx). This is my MySQL update command:

```
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE " + table + " SET " + new_field + " =' " + new_value+ "' WHERE " + field+ "= " + value + "",this.con);
```

this.con is my connection to the MySQL database.

FYI: I use .NET 3.5CF with a mysql.data.cf DLL in Visual Studio 2008.

Could someone help me out with this problem? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: use some kind of print command to make sure there are no leading whitespaces prior to the variable going into the query, then do the same to your query line to make sure its not being added at that stage.  if neither of those show the leading whitespaces, then i would say to try a different library, or maybe a different method.  most languages have a query and an execute method, this seems more generic since it says sqlcommand but still there may be more methods for use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes, you've got a leading space in the SQL:

```
"UPDATE " + table + " SET " + new_field + " =' " + new_value+ "'
```

Note the bit straight after "=" - you've got a quote, then a space, then `new_value`.

However, you shouldn't be putting the values in the SQL directly in the first place - you should be using parameterized SQL statements... currently you've got a SQL injection attack waiting to happen, as well as potential problems for *honest* values with quotes in.

You should use parameterized SQL for both `new_value` and `value` here... I'm assuming that `field` and `table` come from more "trusted" sources?

Comment: The query was just a test. I don't have access to the 'real' database. So in order to test my program I just made a test database with these simple queries. If it get access, I'll parameterize all the values in the queries.

Comment: @BasPalmer: I think it's worth getting into the habit of parameterizing *all* SQL statements so that it's such a firm habit that you *never* accidentally let "prototype" code open up a security hole.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have a space where the * is

```
" ='*" + new_value
```